# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Physics's [fourth moderator election](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: tpg2114] [image: Chris]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Manishearth who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6517230894317568/0).

Comment: On a personal note, I really have appreciated all the hard work Manishearth has done on this site.

Comment: Congrats to tpg2114 and Chris!  Thanks for stepping up to volunteer on this site.

Comment: *:: pikachu face ::*

Comment: Thanks, Jon! Congratulations to the new moderators! Wish you all the luck with the site, glad to see it in good hands!

Answer (score 19):

Congratulations to tpg2114 and Chris! Good to see that some people's fears of one of you not winning can be allayed!

Also, a BIG THANKS to Manish for helping moderate this site! Wish you the best going forwards!